# How to make Canvas set image and text overlay in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a *Congratulation Card Website* where you put your name and then put it into an image all that by JavaScript.

I couldn't render the image with the name. It is just the image in the inspection the SCR is the original image which is supposed to be `data:image`

I try var `dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();`
but I believe I didn't use it correctly
because it only showed the text without the image
but is shown in the inspection the SCR is `data:image`

HTML

```
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center m-5">
        <div class="">
            <div id="img"></div>

            <div class="card p-3" id="form">
                <h1 class="text-center">Make Your Card for Eid</h1>
                <div>
                    <!-- <form action=""> -->
                    <div class="form-group m-3">
                        <label for="name">Write Your Name:<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group m-3">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Choice Your Card:<span
                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <div class="form-check m-3">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Cards" id="exampleRadios1"
                                value="Congratulation-1" required>
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                                <img src="Congratulation-1.png" alt="" id="Congratulation-1" class="cards">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check m-3">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Cards" id="exampleRadios2"
                                value="Congratulation-2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                                <img src="Congratulation-2.png" alt="" id="Congratulation-2" class="cards">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check m-3">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Cards" id="exampleRadios3"
                                value="Congratulation-3">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
                                <img src="Congratulation-3.png" alt="" id="Congratulation-3" class="cards">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check m-3">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Cards" id="exampleRadios4"
                                value="Congratulation-4">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios4">
                                <img src="Congratulation-4.png" alt="" id="Congratulation-4" class="cards">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group m-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn-sda" id="make-card"
                            onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- </form> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value
    var cards = document.getElementsByName("Cards");
    var card

    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        if (cards[i].checked) {
            alert(cards[i].value);
            card = cards[i].value
            break;
        }
    }

    var img = document.getElementById(card);
    img.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous'); // works for me 

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', '900');
    canvas.setAttribute('height', '700');

    var imgFinal = new Image();

    imgFinal.src = card + ".png";

    imgFinal.className = "my-5";
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    
    context.drawImage(imgFinal, 0, 0);
    context.fillStyle = "#fff";
    context.font = "bold 30px serif";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.fillText(name, canvas.width / 2, 550);
    
    var container = document.getElementById("img")
    container.parentNode.insertBefore(imgFinal, container.nextSibling);

    img.removeAttribute("crossorigin"); // works for me
    var form = document.getElementById("form")
    form.remove()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `drawImage()` method and `fillText()` method inside `image.onload` event.  `image.onload` is asynchronous, So `image.src` must be outside of the event scope.

Be sure to use Web Servers like **Xampp** or **Wampp**. Cause it will avoid **Cross Origin** Issues.

Here is the working code :

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center m-5">
    <div class="">
        <div id="img"></div>
        <div class="card p-3" id="form">
            <h1 class="text-center">Make Your Card for Eid</h1>
            <div>
                <!-- <form action=""> -->
                <div class="form-group m-3">
                    <label for="name">Write Your Name:<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group m-3">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Choice Your Card:<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <div class="form-check m-3">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Cards" id="exampleRadios1" value="Congratulation-1" required>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                            <img src="Congratulation-1.png" alt="" id="Congratulation-1" class="cards">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check m-3">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Cards" id="exampleRadios2" value="Congratulation-2">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                            <img src="Congratulation-2.png" alt="" id="Congratulation-2" class="cards">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check m-3">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Cards" id="exampleRadios3" value="Congratulation-3">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
                            <img src="Congratulation-3.png" alt="" id="Congratulation-3" class="cards">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check m-3">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Cards" id="exampleRadios4" value="Congratulation-4">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios4">
                            <img src="Congratulation-4.png" alt="" id="Congratulation-4" class="cards">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group m-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="form-control btn-sda" id="make-card" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
                </div>
                <!-- </form> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    let name = document.getElementById("name").value
    let cards = document.getElementsByName("Cards");
    let card;

    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        if (cards[i].checked) {
            alert(cards[i].value);
            card = cards[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }

    let img = document.getElementById(card);
    // img.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous'); // works for me

    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', '900');
    canvas.setAttribute('height', '700');

    let imgFinal = new Image();
    imgFinal.className = "my-5";
    imgFinal.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

    context.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    imgFinal.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imgFinal, 0, 0);

        context.font = "3em sans-serif";
        context.fillStyle = "#fff";
        context.textAlign = "center";
        context.fillText(name, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

        let newImage = new Image();
        let imgURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        newImage.src = imgURL;

        let container = document.getElementById("img");
        container.parentNode.insertBefore(newImage, container.nextSibling);
    }
    imgFinal.src = `${card}.png`;

    // img.removeAttribute("crossorigin"); // works for me
    let form = document.getElementById("form");
    form.remove();
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks
Cross Origin this was my mian Issue

Comment: Hmmm.. If that's help you . . . It's okay